# Angular 8: Passing html as input variable

Tags: angular, input, angular8

We can use @Input as passing input props or data. We also can use `<ng-content>` to dump a load of html into the children component. Is there any way to pass html as Input. Like @Input html1, @Input html2, and use them in the child class component?

Suppose I have this html in child class:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class="content1 exclusive-css-defined-to-this-component">
     <div>{$content1}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content2 exclusive-css-defined-to-this-component-2">
    <div>{$content2}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I want to pass $content1 & $content2 as input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found the solution, this can be done by:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class="exclusive-css-defined-to-this-component">
     <div><ng-content select="[content1]"></ng-content></div>
  </div>
  <div class="exclusive-css-defined-to-this-component-2">
    <div><ng-content select="[content2]"></ng-content></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And we can use the component like:

```
<wrapper>
   <div content>Any thing you want to put in content1</div>
   <div content2>Any thing you want to put in content2</div>
</wrapper>
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use **innerHTML** to achieve this

Sample example demonstrating this,

parent.component.ts,

```
export class ParentComponent {
  htmlOneAsString = `
    <div>Welcome Text Header</div>
  `;

  htmlTwoAsString = `
    <div>Welcome Text Content</div>
  `;

  htmlAsString = `
    <div><div>${this.htmlOneAsString}</div><div>${this.htmlTwoAsString}</div></div>
  `;
}
```

parent.component.html,

```
<child [innerHTML]="htmlAsString"></child>
```

child.component.ts,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child'
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() htmlAsString: string;
}
```

child.component.html,

```
<div>{{htmlAsString}}</div>
```

Comment: This will not serve my purpose as this way we only can pass a single input. What if we want to pass several props?

Comment: You can form a single html string combining all your htmls in ts file using javascript template string. How about this?

Comment: Updated the answer. Could you please check

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for. I have updated my question. Could you take look?

Answer (score 1):

You can place your html in a string like

```
htmlStr = "<strong>This is an example</strong>";
```

and pass it through to a service:

```
this.whateverService.setHtml(this.htmlStr);
```

then in the receiving component:

```
import { WhateverService } from 'src/app/shared/service/whatever.service';

export class ReceivingComponentThing implements OnInit {
 htmlExample = '';

constructor(private whateverService: WhateverService) {}
}

ngOnInit() {
 // have a getter/setter in service however you like
 this.htmlExample = this.whateverService.getHtmlExample();
}
```

in your template:

```
<div [innerHtml]="htmlExample"><div>
```